# React Native Navigation Custom Header

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation (not react-navigation) and I want to customize the tab bar and top bar. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi! Rhea Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you tried reading the issues of the library on github before posting a question here? I am sure someone has posted that same question. Here https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/390

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the default top bar and use own custom top bar in your component.

```js
component: {
  name: 'Your component',
  options: {
    topBar: {
      visible: false,
      height: 0,
    },
  },
},
```